# Translate two variables and a separator in Swift in 1 string

Tags: swift, localization, nslocalizedstring

I have an item that expires over time. Let's say a user can hold an item 10 days. If 3 days have passed, he has 7 days left. I want to display it like this in English:

```
7/10
```

This takes two arguments and a separator (/). How can I add two variables (7 and 10) and the separator the best way? I can define different separators with the NSLocalizedString, use two stringWithFormats and finally add them together in 1 string. However with this method I need to check if the language is in Right-To-Left. If that is the case the words must be switched.

This looks bad and I was wondering if there is a better way. Is there any way I can make a dictionary and a method that takes two variables and put them in the right way in the separator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a single localized string for NSLocalizedString. For example, the English localized string might be:

> %1$d/%2$d

This acts as your one string format. Then pass your two variables as arguments to this string format.

If you pass 7 and 10 you get 7/10.

Now let’s say in some other language it should be shown as 10:7 then in that language’s strings file, you set the localized string to:

> %2$d:%1$d

I’m assuming your numbers are integers. If they are some other type, change the `d` to the appropriate format specifier.

In either case you pass the same arguments in the same order. The use of positional format specifiers ensures the right values go in the right places.